# Import/Export data in Elastic Search

Tags: python, csv, elasticsearch, backup

I have access to an Elastic Search database but I do not have admin permission which enables me to backup data. I just can query.
How to transfer all data stored in server to another server? there are millions of records. I think it can be good to export all data to csv and then download data. is there a better way? If cdv is the best approach, how to restore data? I've exported my records this way:

```
body = {"query": {match_all": {}}}"


res = es.search(index="mydb", doc_type='entry', body=body)

import csv

with open('static/data/sitemap/data.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, res.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(res)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of open-source projects that you can use to extract all data from your cluster -- your approach of doing a `match_all` won't work correctly.

Here are a few open source projects:

- [Elasticsearch Exporter](https://github.com/mallocator/Elasticsearch-Exporter) = This is a node.js thing, so you have to have to install that also
- [Elasticsearch knapsack](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-knapsack) - This is a plugin, so it probably won't work for your situation
- [Elasticsearch Dump](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump) - This is also node.js based

And if none of those work for you, you can build your own based on the [Scan and Scroll](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html) API for ES.  According to ES's documentation, the [python client](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/index.html) is supposed to have support for the scan and scroll API.

Comment: because match_all only returns a specific number of results... setting it to return all would run ES out of memory... paging through the results a page at a time is inefficient and if you are indexing data while you are doing it, you could get something inconsistant